# Doctrine2, create one entity from another?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctine2\ORM and i have en entity for [user](http://pastie.org/5841492) , and the [role](http://pastie.org/5841489).

When user is registering, i need to create role record with user id and return its id to user, then create the user record, how can i organize my annotation for such work?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default role to your user during `__construct`, then mark the association as `cascade={"persist"}`.

The constructor would look like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->role = new RoleLink();
}
```

I also don't think that a role needs to keep a reference to the user itself, but if need that, keep in mind that in Doctrine 2 ORM you handle associations by assigning related objects to the association property itself (not identifiers!)

Comment: when i creating RoleLink  i need to pass user_id to it, and user_id is null on __construct                                          $this->role = new \Application\Entity\RoleLink($this->getId());

Comment: Why would you need the ID? You can pass directly the user via `$this->role = new RoleLink($this)`.

Comment: Just FYI, the role provider used by BjyAuthorize uses direct access to the DB tables instead of using entities (as it would be supposed to do). I suggest you to use a custom role provider that simply extracts the role from the authenticated user. Don't try to hack around it by setting identifiers or having the role being aware of the user: that's just wrong. I'll address the problem on BjyAuthorize itself as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think you want to create your role entry when a user is registering. I think it's wise to define these upfront (along with their respective access rights).

Once you've taken care of that I guess the obvious relation you're after would be ManyToOne on the User with a persistence cascade set.

```
/**
 * @Table(name="role")
 */
class Role
{

    // possibly define your roles accesses as another realtion or hard code?
}

/**
 * @Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    // id + any other definitions

    /**
     * @var Entities\Role $role
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $role;
}
```

Comment: to create a RoleLink i need to pass user_id to it, and in the constructor user_id is still null

Comment: I believe user should be your owning side. Instantiate your user, then pass the required role object / id reference to it.